# comparing two sorted lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i need to compare 2 lists of countries that i have organised, one by population and one by area, so that it prints out any countries that are in the same position it both lists. so far anything i have tried has resulted in it only returning a single country that has the same position in both lists when there should be a total of 6.

```
def coincidingCountries():
countries = readCountries()
for i in range(0,len(countries)): 
        swap = False
        for j in range(0,len(countries)-(i+1)): 
            if countries[j][1]>countries[j+1][1]:
                temp = countries[j+1] 
                countries[j+1] = countries[j] 
                countries[j] = temp
                swap = True 

for i in range(0,len(countries)):   
        smallest = i
        for j in range(i,len(countries)):
            if countries[j][2]< countries[smallest][2]:
                smallest = j

        temp = countries[i]
        countries[i] = countries[smallest]
        countries[smallest] = temp
```

Comment: Please add your lists or at least a sample of each one.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output for this input. It's unclear for now.

Comment: sounds like a job for `zip` Also -- why are you implementing what looks like bubble sort rather than using a built-in sort?

Answer (score 2):

Try [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

pop = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'i']
area = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f']

countries = pd.DataFrame(data = {'pop': pop, 'area': area})
print countries[countries['area']==countries['pop']]

    area    pop
0   a   a
3   d   d
4   e   e
```

This assumes your two lists are already sorted and will print rows of the table where the values match.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, use python's features
zip(a, b) creates an list of tuples(a_i, b_i) for i between 0 and len(a) provided both arrays are of the same size.

sorted(a, key) sorts an array w.r.t key, so something like:

```
zip(sorted(countries, key=lambda country: country[1]), sorted(countries, key=lambda country: country[2])
```

should do the trick

As a commenter added, you might want to read about list comprehensions.
http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

As for zip and sorted, have a look at the offical docs: 
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html

Comment: Why not put the `zip` inside a list comprehension: `[a for a,b in zip(etc.) if a == b]`?

Comment: Was just writing that part! :)